# Next.js 13 Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to use the data from redux but can't figure out how to get rid of this error. So, I have an app router in next.js 13 and I want to access my page on /settings/account. Here is my folder structure:

```
   --app 
    --settings 
      layout.jsx
      page.jsx
       --account 
         page.jsx
         layout.jsx
```

I want to access user data in the account page:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function AccountPage() {
    const {info: userInfo} = useSelector(state => state.user);
    const {name, id} = userInfo; 
    console.log(name, id)

  return (
    <div>page</div>
  )
}
```

But I get the error: *Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider*. I thought that using layout for wrapping the page would solve the issue so I did this:

```
layout.jsx
"use client"
import { store } from "@/context/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export default function AccountLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
  }
```

Unfortunately, it didn't help. Layout for settings/account page and settings page is the same one but with a different name - SettingsLayout (I thought that root layout would solve the issue). As for settings page it contains only plain HTML and no code.
How can I solve this issue without wrapping `App` component with Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's tested way;

Add a new file called redux-provider.js under your app folder

```
"use client";

import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../store/store"; // tweak the path please

export default function ReduxProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Add another file called provider.tsx under your app folder and implement ReduxProvider

```
"use client";

import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

import ReduxProvider from "./redux-provider";

export default function Providers({ children }: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
    return (
        <ReduxProvider>
            {children}
        </ReduxProvider>
    );
}
```

In your layout.tsx file (immediate child of your app folder), implement Providers

```
import React from "react";

import Providers from './provider';

export default function RootLayout({
   children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Providers>
                    {children}
                </Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Now we can access store from other pages.

**UPDATE**

> Once "use client" is defined in a file, all other modules imported
> into it, including child components, are considered part of the client
> bundle.

True. BUT! Wrapping your root component with ReduxProvider does not necessarily mean that all your other components will be client components. You can still have server components. How?

Add a new folder called experimental under your app folder and then add a new file called page.tsx under the experimental folder. You can get the content of page.tsx file importing from an other file like that.

/experimental/page.tsx

```
import HomePage from "../index"; // this is a client component in which you use redux

export default async function Page() { // this is a server component
    return <HomePage />;
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to wrap my root component in Provider? I would like to keep some components on server side

Comment: I have a small update.

Comment: I've wrapped root component in Redux Provider but unfortunately still got the same error

Comment: My problem was forgetting to use "use client" directive, that's why it didn't work. Thank you a lot for your answer, it helped me to solve the issue even without wrapping root component in Provider.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even though I made a custom `Providers` component which takes the entire app and wraps it in `react-redux` Provider.

Turns out I had to add 'use client' at the top of my component whenever I used `useSelector()` because a Server Component does not send any JavaScript coming from it. So for the code of your hook to make it to the browser, you need a client component.

take a look at this redux-toolkit issues tab:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3228

and this stack overflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76939757/18126831

solved my problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to move the file, which "useSelector", from \app folder to \components folder, error gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35763236)