# Does Next.js always require 'use client' to be able to use a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I was wondering if the only proper way to use Redux within Next.js is to add `'use client'` to every page that uses `useSelector`?

WhenIi don't add `'use client'`, I get this error:

```
- error node_modules\react-redux\lib\components\Context.js (12:44) @ getContext
- error TypeError: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function
    at Home (./app/page.js:39:81)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

I thought that using `'use client'` would cause a worse page load time by increasing the amount of code being executed by the client.

My idea was to use Next.js to create a Frontpage that is static but, if logged in, would show a dashboard button, by simply checking if the Redux state with the login token is empty.

I'm new to Next.js.

Comment: Yes. Because you can't use hooks in React Server Components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have `useSelector` in a component, you have to add `"use client"`. That's because, for a [Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components), the idea is to not send any JavaScript coming from it. So for the code of your hook to make it to the browser, you need a client component. And it's okay, as Lee Robinson from Vercel [says](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1577133328):

> Client Components aren't a de-opt, nor a cop-out. You can think of Server Components as an additive to the existing model. I understand the sentiment of wanting to use Server Components for lots of things (not bad!) but it's also totally okay to use Client Components for certain things.

Also, [even a client component first renders on the server with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300847/getting-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-even-after-adding-use-clien). So, wanting beyond is like wanting interactivity with only HTML, which the browser itself doesn't know how to do.