# Passing client side data to server component in NextJS 13.4 App Router to rerender

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a landing page for a Quran App in Next JS 13.4. This page consists of two main components: Hero and SurahList.

Hero is a static component that contains a search box.
SurahList is a server component that fetches a list of Surahs from an API.
I want to implement a search filter within my Hero component that allows me to filter through my SurahList items based on the name of the Surah. The aim is to have the page update the list per search without having to convert the SurahList into a client-side render component.

**src/app/page.tsx**

```
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import SurahList from './components/SurahList';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className='container mx-auto'>
        <Hero />
        <SurahList />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**src/app/components/Hero.tsx**

```
'use client';

export default function Hero() {
  // function handleSearch(term){
  // }
  return (
    <div className='hero h-full bg-base-300'>
      <div className='hero-content text-center'>
        <div className='max-w-md'>
          // ... (skipping for brevity)
            <div className='input-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Search…'
                className='input input-bordered'
                // onChange={(e) => {
                // handleSearch(e.target.value)
                // }}
              />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**src/app/components/SurahList.tsx**

```
import { Key } from 'react';
import Surah, { surahProps } from './Surah';

async function getData() {
  'use server';
  const res = await fetch('http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/surah');

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data from api');
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function SurahList() {
  const { data } = await getData();

  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mt-4 px-3 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-4  xl:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-4'>
      {data.map((a: surahProps, index: Key | null | undefined) => {
        return (
          <Surah
            key={index}
            name={a.name}
            number={a.number}
            englishName={a.englishName}
            englishNameTranslation={a.englishNameTranslation}
            numberOfAyahs={a.numberOfAyahs}
            revelationType={a.revelationType}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this, perhaps by passing a function or state from `Hero` to `SurahList` without breaking the server-side rendering aspect of `SurahList`? And is this best practice in NextJS 13.4?

I have tried looking online for similar questions and solutions and there doesn't seem to be any without making SurahList client side render, passing states etc

Comment: If you need client interactivities like searching, don't be afraid of using client components. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/76939757/15288641.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Yep, I intend on doing so for the component Hero.tsx which will have the Search Filter functionality, however to re-render/update/rehydrate the `data` response in SurahList.tsx, to only show the filtered responses, is there a way of doing so without making SurahList.tsx client rendered too?

Answer (score 0):

Move the fetch functionality to the parent `page.tsx` and pass it to the client components. You have to make both search and list in a client component or move them together the a shared client component [(lifting state up)](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example).

In the client component make a state and complete your functionality.

See also [cmdk](https://cmdk.paco.me/)