# How can I use searchParams in Layout with SSR?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am creating platform that has pagination in layout. I don't want to make this layout client side for SEO and Speed. How can I access my searchParams in layout component with SSR ?

Comment: You cannot so far. Chekcout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939269/does-next-js-always-require-use-client-to-be-able-to-use-a-hook.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nextjs App router, you can use the userSearchParams hook to do that, simply by having the next code:

```js
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

You can find further details in the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params)

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to change my component to client component. It's ridiculous to change all data from server side to client side for just 1 searchParams.

Comment: Can you share your component? it would make it easier to understand your logic. But I have seen an approach where you can have the items that will use the searchParams as different component and then import them.

Comment: I'd agree with you that I'd also like to avoid changing everything into client components; however, my understanding is that you'd make *that specific component* a client component, not everything. Your other components, especially your `layout.tsx`, should still be used  as server components. Let us know if you've made progress and found better solutions, or if you can provide additional info. I'm looking to refactor on my end as well.